# Is it possible to change or upgrade cars by replacing parts?

Tags: need-for-speed-the-run

In this new game can you upgrade the engine and body parts of your car like you could in NFS Underground?   Or is it more like NFS Hot Pursuit, where you mainly pick the car and drive in an arcade style of race?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be the latter case. You can't customize the cars

[Source](http://news.tgn.tv/need-for-speed-the-run-no-customization/)

Comment: Ty and thats no fun :(. I spent hours in NSF underground 2 just designing my cars and testing what I had just tuned and so on, I had a blast but the last few NFS seem to be a bit blan